# Using spinner as global service

Tags: angular, typescript, spinner, service-locator

I am using the following spinner from the [ng2-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin) theme:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BaThemeSpinner {

  private _selector:string = 'preloader';
  private _element:HTMLElement;

  constructor() {
    this._element = document.getElementById(this._selector);
  }

  public show():void {
    this._element.style['display'] = 'block';
  }

  public hide(delay:number = 0):void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._element.style['display'] = 'none';
    }, delay);
  }
}
```

So for each component I have to import it, and I want to avoid it, because many components will use it. How can I make it available to the whole application?

Comment: Importing from each consumer has some benefits, mainly calling out the dependency. Imagine searching for and replacing this later without an `import {SpinnerService} from ...` line.

Comment: But the spinner service specifically in an app is usually the same for all the components. If it changes then the whole app would be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a base component and put a getter like

```
export class BaseView {

    protected _injector:Injector;

    protected _spinnerService:SpinnerService;

    constructor() {
        let providers = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([SpinnerService]);
        this._injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(providers);
    }

    get spinnerService(): SpinnerService { 
        if (this._spinnerService == null) {
            this._spinnerService = this._injector.get(SpinnerService);
        }
        return this._spinnerService;
    }
}
```

then use it:

```
this.spinnerService.show()
```

**ReflectiveInjector** can be found inside of **@angular/core**

Docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ReflectiveInjector-class.html

Comment: what appInjector is? where do you import it from?

Comment: @FacundoGFlores `import {Injector} from '@angular/core';`

Comment: @FacundoGFlores I have updated the answer, remember this is a service locator pattern, just for your information.